# How to open new tab with Iron:Router and Pass some data in Meteor.js?

Tags: meteor

I would like to open new tab with Iron:Router. How can I open new tab with `Router.go()` and Pass some data?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For Example you have a profile route with the `_id` of the user, this will work.

```
 Router.go('/profile',Meteor.userId())
```

Comment: thanks but It doesn't open new tab. How can I open the new tab with Router.go() function?

Comment: Hi @Phirum check [this related SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript) you can do it with plain javascript, with iron router, you only will get a refresh page with `router.go` you can do something like this, using javascript + iron:router `window.open(Router.url(path, params, someQueryt));` following this syntaxis

Comment: Ethaan is correct, you need `window.open(url)` to open a new window and then it's only a question of generating the url you want.

Comment: thank @Ethaan and @Michel Floyd. It works with `window.open();`